# WD External Drive, want to use a different hard drive in it

Tags: hard-drive, drivers, external-hard-drive

I have a WD MyBook 1TB external drive. I recently put the hard drive in my desktop and wanted to use the enclosure with other hard drives. I tried this and get driver errors.

I am using Windows 7 Pro 64bit.
I've hunted around for drivers and looked through forums for help but can't seem to figure it out.

If any one can help me use my WD enclosure with non-WD hard drives, I would be very happy.

Model: WD10000H1CS-00

Comment: What kind of driver errors do you get?

Comment: unknown driver mostly, and HID driver error

Comment: Isn't the connectors all propitiatory?

Comment: If that's the case than that's fine, I just want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some external USB hard drives now use proprietary Sata connections inside, others may have something in the USB firmware to prevent re-use of the enclosure with different hard drives than originally came in them, another reason to build your own external USB hard drive.

Here is a picture (left) of a Western Digital 2.5" proprietary hard drive that came out of a USB enclosure they manufactured Sept 2009.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to assume it's the custom firmware.
Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: Maybe its a brand issue, only a WD drive will work, just a guess.